# How to add text to image padding in HTML?

Tags: html, text, padding

I'm trying to add a text both top and bottom of my image in the HTML file. It should be in white text and go onto the padding-top and padding-bottom, but I'm not sure how to add this/align this to my black padding. I want to ideally use HTML, and avoid CSS, but can use if needed.

For example, I have an image with black padding, and want to add "CLICK HERE" to the bottom padding and similarly, to the top e.g. "Kittens"

```html
<div><img style="background-color: black; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 50px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 30px; float: right;"src="https://www.sciencenews.org/sites/default/files/2019/07/main/articles/072319_ee_cat-allergy_feat.jpg" alt="Kittens"; width="150" height="100" /></div>

<p><a href = "https://www.sciencenews.org">CLICK HERE</a></p>
```

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, but you must start by making the `a` tags and the `img` tag children of the same parent.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the styles in the `img` tag put them in the parent `div`_

like this:

```html
<div style="background-color: black; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 50px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 30px; float: right; text-align: center;">
    
    <span style="color: #FFFFFF;">Some Other Text</span>
    <br />
    <img src="https://www.sciencenews.org/sites/default/files/2019/07/main/articles/072319_ee_cat-allergy_feat.jpg" alt="Kittens"; width="150" height="100" />
    <br />
    <span><a style="color: #FFFFFF;" href = "https://www.sciencenews.org">CLICK HERE</a></span>

</div>
```

Note:

I also added a `text-align: center;` to the `<div>` styles _

and a style of `color: #FFFFFF;` to the `<a>` tag

Comment: Thank you! But how would you be able to add another text up above that picture?

Comment: @mcoder _ I've updated the code to answer the question in your comment

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to answer your question, check out below given codes.

```css
div{
background-color: black; 
padding-left: 10px;
padding-bottom: 50px; 
padding-right: 10px; 
padding-top: 30px; 
float: right; 
text-align: center;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div >

    <img src="https://www.sciencenews.org/sites/default/files/2019/07/main/articles/072319_ee_cat-allergy_feat.jpg" alt="Kittens"; width="150" height="100" />
    <br/><br/>
   <a  href = "https://www.sciencenews.org">CLICK HERE</a>

</div>
```

```css
.box-card {
  float:right;
  background-color:black;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 150px;
  
}
.container {
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
p,div{
text-align:center;
}
a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;

  }
```

```html
<div class="box-card">
<div class="container">
    <p> </p> 
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.sciencenews.org/sites/default/files/2019/07/main/articles/072319_ee_cat-allergy_feat.jpg"  style="width:80%">
  <div class="container">
    <p><a href = "https://www.sciencenews.org">CLICK HERE</a></p>

  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.box-card {
  background-color:black;
  float:right;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 150px;
}
.box-card{
padding:12px;
}
.container {
  padding:3px 8px;
}
p,div{
text-align:center;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="box-card">
<div class="container">
    <p> </p> 
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.sciencenews.org/sites/default/files/2019/07/main/articles/072319_ee_cat-allergy_feat.jpg"  style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <p><a href = "https://www.sciencenews.org">CLICK HERE</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```